# Having a shell script default to execution

Tags: shell-script, centos

I created a simple shell script to run a jar file. I'd like to be able to simply double click the file to execute it, rather than needing to run it through terminal.

I don't think it's relevant, but I am running CentOS 7.

Comment: What desktop manager (Gnome, KDE etc.) are you using?

Comment: I'm using Gnome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### 1: Create an executable wrapper script

Most modern desktop environments will automatically run files marked as executable when you click on it. Simply create a simple wrapper script that runs the command you want with your favorite plain text editor with the following contents:

```
#!/bin/bash
java -jar /path/to/app.jar
```

and make it executable from your favorite file manager or by running

```
chmod +x /path/to/script.sh
```

Now when you navigate to the directory that contains your script from your file manager you should be able to click (or double click depending on your file manager) to execute the file.

Note however that some file managers might not support running scripts in this way or throw up a warning that you are executing a command. Most scripts are generally run from the cli and generally people create desktop entry files to launch applications from their desktop application menu.

### 2: Create a desktop entry file

Desktop entry files are a files that tell linux desktop environments what applications you have installed, how to run them and a bunch of other metadata about them (such as a friendly name and icon).

A minimal desktop entry file will look like:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=Your Apps Name
Exec=java -jar /path/to/app.jar
Categories=Utility;Java;
```

Your desktop environment might have a way to create these files for you (check the settings, menu or right click on the desktop - it varies depending on desktop environment). Or you can create them manually using your favorite plain text editor and creating a file in `~/.local/share/applications` that ends in `.desktop` such as `~/.local/share/applications/your-script.desktop` with the contents above.

Desktop files have the advantage over wrapper scripts as they are added to your desktop environment's menu system and can often be placed in the system bar or on your desktop like any other application.

The archlinux has an execllent guide on creating desktop files on their [wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Desktop_entries) or you can read the freedesktop.org specs [here](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/desktop-entry-spec-latest.html#introduction) for all the different things you can do with desktop files.

Comment: While I'm still having issues, I think they're far enough beyond the scope of this question that I'd ought to ask a new one. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a file.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
echo 'run script'
sleep 20
```

Then you have to make it executable

```
sudo chmod ugo+x file.sh
```

After that you can double click if the desktop manager is set to execute or at least ask instead of just open the .sh file with your default text editor.

Comment: You do not need to use `sudo` to make a file executable if you own the file. You can also omit the ugo and simply `chmod +x file.sh`